# Delete childnode from DOM

Tags: php, dom, html-lists, parent-child, removechild

I need to remove child node p from li with php

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <p>Some text</p>
 <li>
<ol>
```

Part of my code

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($contenido);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
      $li->removeAttribute('class');
      $li->removeAttribute('style');
      $li->parentNode->removeChild('p');
    }
```

But nothing happen, what goin on?

Answer (score 0):

#### first you forget `/` in `</li>` tage

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <p>Some text</p>
 </li>
<ol>
```

##### second try to add the tage in variabel

```
$lis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');    
foreach ($lis as $li) {
          $li->removeAttribute('class');
          $li->removeAttribute('style');
          $li->parentNode->removeChild('p');
        }
```

try to see the documentation from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: Thank's for your answer, this method is not workig, /li was an error finger,,, moving $dom->getElementsByTagName('li'); to variable is exactly same as not do it